# How would I identify an authenticated user in an eloquent query JSON output for a messenger system?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've built a messenger system between two users and I need to be able to identify the authenticated user in an eloquent JSON output.

**Conversation Controller**

```
public function show(Conversation $conversation)
 {
   $conversation->load('participants');
   $messages = $conversation->messages()->with('sender')->latest()->take(5)->get()->sortBy('created_at');

   return $messages->toArray();
}
```

**Conversation Model**

```
public function participants(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User' ,'conversation_participants','conversation_id','user_id');
}
```

**JSON Output**

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":59,
      "body":"Hi, what's up",
      "conversation_id":11,
      "sender_id":1,
      "type":"user_message",
      "created_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:07",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:07",
      "sender":{  
         "id":1,
         "username":"Jim",
         "slug":"Jim",
         "name":"Jim",
      }
   },
   "0":{  
      "id":60,
      "body":"Hi there",
      "conversation_id":11,
      "sender_id":1,
      "type":"user_message",
      "created_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:20",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:20",
      "sender":{  
         "id":1,
         "username":"Reggie",
         "slug":"reggie",
         "name":"Reggie",
      }
   }
}
```

So let's say I'm logged in as "Jim" I would want some identifier in the JSON output like a `"logged_in":"1"` property as the identifier to show Jim is the logged in user and `"logged_in":"0"` to show Reggie is not the logged in user:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":59,
      "body":"Hi, what's up",
      "conversation_id":11,
      "sender_id":1,
      "type":"user_message",
      "created_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:07",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:07",
      "sender":{  
         "id":1,
         "username":"Jim",
         "slug":"Jim",
         "name":"Jim",
         "logged_in":"1"
      }
   },
   "0":{  
      "id":60,
      "body":"Hi there",
      "conversation_id":11,
      "sender_id":1,
      "type":"user_message",
      "created_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:20",
      "updated_at":"2018-10-01 23:43:20",
      "sender":{  
         "id":1,
         "username":"Reggie",
         "slug":"reggie",
         "name":"Reggie",
         "logged_in":"0"
      }
   }
}
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

*Note* The indentifier doesn't need doesn't need to be in the "sender" object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to `SELECT` another column as follows:

```
$messages = $conversation
    ->messages()
    ->selectRaw('messages.*, IF(messages.sender_id = ?, 1, 0) AS logged_in', [Auth::id()])
    ->with('sender')
    ->latest()
    ->take(5)
    ->get()
    ->sortBy('created_at');
```

Note, I've assumed you're using MySQL.

Comment: I am using MySql. I'm not getting the other fields with that output. I'm only getting:
`{"0":{"logged_in":1,"sender":null}` also will this be able to be paginated?

Comment: I've updated the `selectRaw()`. Reading the source, I thought it added a new `SELECT`, rather than overwrite the previous. Give this a go. And yes, it should paginate fine.

Comment: How would I paginate for future reference? I'm getting an exception thrown `$messages = $conversation
      ->messages()
      ->selectRaw('messages.*, IF(messages.sender_id = ?, 1, 0) AS logged_in', [Auth::id()])
      ->with('sender')
      ->latest()
      ->sortBy('created_at')
      ->paginate(15);`

Comment: Your calls to `latest()` and `sortBy('created_at')` shouldn't go together, as they sort on the same field in opposite directions. But with pagination, what's the exception?

Comment: Ah thanks, I just noticed that it works without sortBy, before I was getting pagination method doesn't exist I'm getting sortBy doesn't exist`"message": "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::sortBy does not exist.",`

I'm guessing I was redundantly using sortBy?

Comment: In your original code, you're calling `sortBy` on the `Collection` returned by the Eloquent query. In the code from your comment, you're calling `sortBy` on the `Query\Builder`. The method is on the `Query\Builder` is actually called `orderBy`, so that's the problem.